# Power Pivot - Inner Join like access, calculate and show grand total, possible?

Tags: powerpivot

I'm trying to acive the following with power pivot. Still couldn't figure out how. Is it possible?

[Example from access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhWAg.png)

Gourped by “MatNr”. “Qty cases” are summed. From the “tbl_Weight” show the “Cases on trolley”  per material. Divide “summed Qty cases” by “Cases on trolley” and show the results in the fourth column. Most importantly total the “summed Qty cases” column and the “Nr of trolleys per mat” column.

Two tables:
tbl_Sales
MatNr   Qty cases
4564    100
4654    565
4564    100
4654    50

tbl_Weight
MatNr   Cases on trolley
4564    10
4654    20

Query:

SELECT tbl_Sales.MatNr, Sum(tbl_Sales.[Qty cases]) AS [SummevonQty cases], tbl_Weight.[Cases on trolley], Sum([Qty cases]/[Cases on trolley]) AS [Nr of trolleys per mat]
FROM tbl_Sales INNER JOIN tbl_Weight ON tbl_Sales.MatNr = tbl_Weight.MatNr
GROUP BY tbl_Sales.MatNr, tbl_Weight.[Cases on trolley];

Expected results:

MatNr   SummevonQty cases   Cases on trolley    Nr of trolleys per mat
4564           200                10                         20
4654           615                20                       30.75
Totals         815                                         50.75

Comment: Hi Priyan. In order to help the community here better answer your question, I would recommend that you try to anonymize and simplify your data as much as possible, and share a snippet/screenshot right here. Simplification is very important for future readers who will have similar questions as you, and for the experts here who should not need to study your entire business context before answering the question. If your question involves looking into an excel/access file right off the bat, then it is not simplified enough to be on Stackoverflow. Good luck.